# Intent Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.image_resep) must not be null

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-intent

i got some error for my code. when i open it crash

this is my code in DetailResep.kt

```
class DetailResep : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.list_resep)

    val tvNama: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)

    val name = intent.getStringExtra(NAME)
    val detail = intent.getStringExtra(DETAIL)

    tvNama.text = name

    //my problem code
    val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_resep)
    val image = intent.getIntExtra(IMAGE, R.drawable.tumis_buncis)
    imageView.setImageResource(image)
}

companion object {
    const val DETAIL = "detail"
    const val NAME = "name"
    const val IMAGE = "image"
}
```

}

then this my xml code. i want to change image in id.image_resep

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/detail_resep"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_resep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ayam_teriyaki"/>

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/frm_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#00CC00"
            android:text="@string/resep_name" />
```

when i open this xml i got error code. then i check on  java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.image_resep) must not be null

Comment: Your R.id.image_resep is null and it should not be?

Comment: yes, when i declare on my textview -> not error, but when i declare my imageview -> error null exception. i want to change image in imageview. plase help me

Comment: can you show your error log?

Comment: its kotlin you can direct call this with id   i think you are calling some other xml data  image_resep